# BATCH - Remove "" and line diference in batch

Tags: file, batch-file, cmd

I need a little help here,

How can i remove all the " from the first line without touching the second line and then join the two lines as one?
This is in a txt file and i need the change to be made in it.

line1->

```
curl "https://localhost:1234/wle//505?action=god&params="
```

line 2-> with more than 9000 characters

```
{"some text to join after params= that contains" and {}[]/,:"}
```

Hope someone can help.
Thanks

Comment: without double quoting the URL you've to escape chars otherwise being interpreted by cmd.exe when executing the lines `&` -> `^&`  A `"` in a string enclosed in double quotes can be escaped with a backslash. Otherwise your question is unclear to me.

Comment: Please ignore line1-> and line2->, they are just to explain how its presented in text file. An yes, second line starts with {

Comment: AS [SO] is aa programmers site, you should edit the question to  show the code you have and the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

**edited** to match comment `9000 characters, and cmd cant hold that many characters` (simple: write first line without line feed, add second line):
(if there still are too many characters, [jrepl.bat](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=6044) can help)

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
<c.txt (
  set /p "line1="
  set /p "line2="
)
<nul >c.txt set /p "=!line1:"=!"
>>c.txt echo %line2%
```

read the two lines into two variables, write both back to file, removing the quotes from the first one.

Note: [Delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) might/might not be needed for each of the variables (maybe separately), depending on present characters. (here the `&` in the first line needs delayed expansion).

another **edit** to match `only the second line.` Process the first line as above. For the second line, just use `more +1`. This will work regardless of the line length. Contra: you have to use a secondary file.  Pro: no problems with special chars (in the second line).

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
<c.txt set /p "line1="
<nul >c.out set /p "=!line1:"=!"
more +1 c.txt >>c.out
move /y c.out c.txt
```

Comment: cant do that because the file is generated by a tool and have 9000 characters, and cmd cant hold that many characters, thats why i need to do it in the file its in, something like a replace in line 1

Comment: each of the lines or both lines together 9000 chars?

Comment: only the second line.

Answer (score 0):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

< input.txt (
   set /P "line="
   < NUL set /P "=!line:"=!"
   findstr "^"
) > output.txt
move /Y output.txt input.txt
```